# How to stop the recursion in prolog, once the desired value is returned?

Tags: recursion, prolog

The .pl file that I am consulting looks like this

```
spouse(eddard_stark,catelyn_stark).
spouse(X,Y):-spouse(Y,X).
```

What I fundamentally wanted program here was that *if 'Eddard is spouse of Catelyn' then 'Catelyn is spouse of Eddard'.*

But when I query `spouse(eddard_stark, X).` this goes into an endless recursive return of `catelyn_stark` .
I am not sure how to stop recursion in Prolog once desired output is reached.

Also if you think of any alternate solution for this problem please mention it, I highly appreciate your views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will keep swapping the parameters endlessly. You can solve this problem by using *two* predicates, one `spouse_data/2` for example that contains:

```
spouse_data(eddard_stark,catelyn_stark).
```

and then a predicate `spouse/2` that tries to call the predicate in two directions:

```
spouse(X, Y) :-
    spouse_data(X, Y).
spouse(X, Y) :-
    spouse_data(Y, X).
```

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I wanted and also thanks for the speedy response.

Comment: Right. Instead of specifying that `spouse/2` is a symmetric relation, you stratify it into two predicates. It's a good solution, and it shows that Prolog's is strong for programming (for building certain proofs), but weak for modeling in FOL. 