# Prolog Issue Infinite Loop Beginner

Tags: prolog, infinite-loop

I'm trying to write a prolog rule about someone's sister being searched. It's really quite simple, but I get caught in an infinite loop.

Given ->

```
male(john).
male(hubert).
male(jude).

female(alice).
female(jane).
female(isabella).

issibling( john  , hubert ).
issibling( alice , bob    ).
issibling( alice , jane   ).
issibling( Y     , X      ) :- issibling(X,Y).
```

My Rule->

```
issister(X,Y) :- issibling(X,Y), female(X).
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're not the first with this problem:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15328936/trying-to-implement-commutativity-in-prolog. Alternativly you have to limit recursion in issibling by a counter or so

Comment: The problem is that `issibling(Y,X) :- issibling(X,Y)` will keep swapping the parameters. You can fix this by using two predicates: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63317196/67579